# How to simulate a mouse click using selenium java-script-executor for hammer implementation?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, hammer.js

I have to move a component from one position to another position which receives hammer **pan** events. We write a mouse event stimulating java script code but it failed.

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)chromeDriv).ExecuteScript("function simulate(f,c,d,e) {var b,a=null;for(b in eventMatchers)if(eventMatchers[b].test(c)){a=b;break}if(!a)return!1;document.createEvent?(b=document.createEvent(a),a==\"HTMLEvents\"?b.initEvent(c,!0,!0):b.initMouseEvent(c,!0,!0,document.defaultView,0,d,e,d,e,!1,!1,!1,!1,0,null),f.dispatchEvent(b)):(a=document.createEventObject(),a.detail=0,a.screenX=d,a.screenY=e,a.clientX=d,a.clientY=e,a.ctrlKey=!1,a.altKey=!1,a.shiftKey=!1,a.metaKey=!1,a.button=1,f.fireEvent(\"on\"+c,a));return!0} var eventMatchers={HTMLEvents:/^(?:load|unload|abort|error|select|change|submit|reset|focus|blur|resize|scroll)$/,MouseEvents:/^(?:click|dblclick|mouse(?:down|up|over|move|out))$/};simulate(arguments[0],\"mouseover\",0,0); simulate(arguments[0],\"mousemove\",arguments[1],arguments[2]); simulate(arguments[0],\"mouseup\",arguments[1],arguments[2]); ", LocatorFrom, xto, yto);
```

Any good ideas? 
thanks in advance

Comment: Try Selenium Actions for it. https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html

Comment: @selva tried it by browser action and result be same, found that only *panend* event triggered for both java-script and browser action execution.